# Renaming files using hash table in perl

Tags: perl, file

I have made a perl code which is shown below. Here what I am trying to do is first get input from a text file consisting of a HTTP URL with a Title.
thus the first regex is the title and the second regex fetches the id from inside the URL.
All these values are inserted into the hash table %myfilenames().

So this hash table has key as the URL id, and value as the Title. Everything till here works fine, now I have a set of files on my computer which have the ID in their name which we extracted from the URL.

What I want to do is that if the ID is there in the hash table, then the files name should change to the value assigned to the ID. Now the output at the print statement in the last function is correct but I am unable to rename the files. I tried many things, but nothing works. Can someone help please.

example stuff:

```
URL: https://abc.com/789012 <--- ID
Value (new Title) : ABC
file name on computer = file-789012 <---- ID
new file name = ABC
```

My code:

```
use File::Slurp;
use File::Copy qw(move);
open( F, '<hadoop.txt' );

$key   = '';
$value = '';

%myfilenames = ();
foreach (<F>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /Lecture/ ) {
        $value = $_;
    }
    if ( $_ =~ /https/ ) {
        if ( $_ =~ /\d{6}/ ) {
            $key = $&;
        }
    }

    if ( !( $value eq '' || $key eq '' ) ) {

        #print "$key\t\t$value";
        $myfilenames{$key} = $value;
        $key               = '';
        $value             = '';
    }

}

#while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %myfilenames ) { print "$k $v\n"; }

my @files = read_dir 'C:\\inputfolder';

for (@files) {
    if ( $_ =~ /\d{6}/ ) {
        $oldval = $&;
    }
    $newval = $myfilenames{$oldval};
    chomp($newval);
    print $_ , "\t\t$newval" . "\n";
    $key = '';
}
```

Comment: The desired action is that my file names in the directory get renamed to the value inside the hash table. (Where the ID inside file name is equal to ID inside URL)

Comment: Did you try `rename`?

Comment: How did you use it? Did you prepend `C:\inputfolder` to each file name?

Comment: Yes I did try with and without appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't prepend the path to the file names. The following works for me (on a Linux box):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Slurp qw{ read_dir };

my $dir = 0;
mkdir $dir;
open my $FH, '>', "$dir/$_" for 123456, 234567;

my $key = my $value = q();
my %myfilenames = ();

for (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $value = $_ if /Lecture/;
    $key   = $1 if /https/ and /(\d{6})/;

    if ($value ne q() and $key ne q()) {
        $myfilenames{$key} = $value;
        $key = $value = q();
    }
}

my @files = read_dir($dir);

for (@files) {
    if (/(\d{6})/) {
        my $oldval = $1;
        my $newval = $myfilenames{$oldval};
        rename "$dir/$oldval", "$dir/$newval";
    }
}

__DATA__
Lecture A1
https://123456
# Comment
Lecture A2
https://234567
```

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work, then I noticed that the rename function was failing due to Permission denied. Dunno why this is happening

Comment: @chettyharish Whenever doing file operations, I'd recommend always including a [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) after your `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  It will help catch things like this.

Comment: Using Ubuntu did the trick. Still not sure why it will not work in Windows no matter what